# Оставлять константными толщину и размер элипсов при масштабировании

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

При масштабировании, требуется оставить элипс прежнего размера и прежней толщиной, но в тех же координатах. Тестирую с методом `setCosmetic()`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRectF
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
       
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        zoomInFactor = 1.15
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Das")
        self.w = GraphicsView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)
        self.penWidth = 10
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.drawLine()

    def drawLine(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 20
        self._x = 40
        self._y = 50
        el = SimpleItem(self.penWidth, self.x, self.y)
        self.w.scene().addItem(el)


class SimpleItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, width, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.penWidth = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(width, x, y)

    def boundingRect(self):
        self.p = QRectF(-self.penWidth/2, -self.penWidth/2, self.penWidth, self.penWidth)
        return self.p

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        pen.setCosmetic(True)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 6, 6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А `self.scale` зачем делать, если масштабирование нежелательно? Можете описать суть вашей задачи?

Comment: @gil9red при масштабировании элипса,как пример, увеличивается его толщина отрисовки и диаметр элипса. Для моей задачи требуется масштабировать его так,чтобы его технические характеристики(диаметр, толщина) оставались прежними.

Comment: Кст, советую в вью указать `self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)`, тогда будет хорошее сглаживание :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте элементу флаг [QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum):

```
...
class SimpleItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, width, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.penWidth = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
        ...
```

Comment: Дополнительные примеры по теме вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222914/

Comment: или элипс меняет координаты или одно из двух. Как это лечится?

Comment: @ShevIv, не, скорее это что-то сценой или с вью происходит. Добавьте `print(self.x, self.y)` в `paint` у элемента и убедитесь, что его координаты не меняются. Возможно, дело в `self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())`, но это только предположение